# Data truncation: Data too long for column 'path' at row 2

Tags: mysql

When I try to run below query I receive below error:

> Data truncation: Data too long for column 'path' at row 2

```
with recursive links as( select
j.id,
concat(p.pkey,'-',j.issuenum) as Task,
(select pname from jiradb.issuetype t where j.issuetype = t.id) Type,
cast(j.id as char(100)) AS path,
coalesce((SELECT cfv.stringvalue
FROM   jiradb.customfieldvalue cfv
LEFT   JOIN jiradb.customfield cf ON cf.id = cfv.customfield
WHERE  cf.cfname = 'Epic Name'
AND    cfv.issue = j.id),'No Epic Name') EpicName
from jiradb.jiraissue j
-- project
join jiradb.project p on j.project = p.id
-- issuetype
join jiradb.issuetype t on j.issuetype = t.id and t.pname = 'Epic'
where instr('(E)139899','(E)') and j.id = replace('(E)139899','(E)','')

union all

select
i.destination as id,
concat(p.pkey,'-',j.issuenum) as Task,
(select pname from jiradb.issuetype t where j.issuetype = t.id) Type,
concat(l.path, '/', coalesce((SELECT DATE(cfv.datevalue)
FROM   jiradb.customfieldvalue cfv
LEFT   JOIN jiradb.customfield cf ON cf.id = cfv.customfield
WHERE  cf.cfname = 'Planed start date'
AND    cfv.issue = i.destination),date('9999-12-31')), '/',
coalesce((select date(j.duedate) from jiradb.jiraissue j where j.id = i.destination),date('9999-12-31')), '/', i.destination)  AS path,
l.EpicName
from (  -- get the links for epic, tasks and subtasks
select source as source, destination as destination from jiradb.issuelink where linktype in (10200,10100)
and destination not in (select source from jiradb.issuelink where linktype = 10401)
union
-- get the links for stories
select destination as source, source as destination from jiradb.issuelink where linktype = 10401
) i
-- links
join links l on i.source = l.id
-- Jiraissue
join jiradb.jiraissue j on i.destination = j.id
-- project
join jiradb.project p on j.project = p.id
)
 select * from links
```

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75811273/edit) accordingly.

Comment: As the error correctly suggests :

`To avoid the data truncation error, the size of the 'path' column in the database table needs to be increased as it cannot accommodate the current length of the data being inserted.`  Please let us know; if you still face issues

Answer (score 0):

Modify the column structure in the table to allow for a longer length to accommodate the data you want to insert.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name
MODIFY COLUMN path VARCHAR(20);
```